# How do i translate text in a table Using JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is the code i wish to translate to French

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>           
            <th>Description (French)</th>          
        </tr>

        <tr>           
            <td><p id="desc_F_T"></p></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The text for that table data is retrieved from a weather API with the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,CA&appid=[apiKey]', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#desc_F_T").html(data.weather[0].description)
  });
});
```

I want to now translate that text to French, how do I do that using Jquery/Javascript?
Note: I do not want to translate the entire page, just that single table data.

Comment: [RTM](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api#multi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `&lang=fr` to your request as seen in the [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api#multi)